# I lost my original photo when i cropped using shotwell

Tags: shotwell

I did a crop on the original photo. The cropping picture has replaced the original photo. Now I lost my original photo.

**Is there any chance of recovering my original photo?**

Note : revert to original is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only way to restore your original is to restore from a back-up... :-(

Comment: Although there is a small chance that something like Photorec might be able to recover it.